# Can not delete files on data lake store created by HDinsight activity

Tags: azure, hive, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight

I am not able to `delete` the files created by `Python/Scala/Hive` programs on associated `Azure Datalake Store`. When I try to `delete` those folders & files I receive `access denied error`. I ensured I have `full permission` on these folders and files.

Any help appreciated.[image]

Comment: It solved. I gave permission to myself as owner in IAM. Now able to delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to re-check the permissions.

**Note:** To delete a file, you only need write and execute on the parent folder (adl://mydatalakestore.azuredatalakestore.net/folder/).

Permissions needed to delete a file:

[image]

- For the parent folder, the caller needs **Write + Execute** permissions.
- For all the other folders in the file’s path, the caller needs **Execute permissions**.

**Note:** Write permissions on the file are not required to delete it as long as the previous two conditions are true.

For more details, refer “[Access control in Azure Data Lake Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control)”.

Comment: All required permissions are there

Comment: @HemantChandurkar I would request you to follow the steps outlined here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/37221d47-a71b-42f8-ac7d-b7ab36ccd209/not-able-to-delete-foldersfiles-created-by-hdinsight-cluster-itself-as-mask-is-being-used?forum=hdinsight

Answer (score 0):

Note that you must have permissions to all files and subfolders under the parent folder you are trying to delete.  You can make sure this is the case by recursively setting permissions via the portal.  View the parent folder which you're trying to delete, click Access, verify your permissions are set correctly, click Advanced, then click "Apply to children".

You must wait with the browser window active while this completes.  If you have many files, this may take a while (if you have millions of files, then you'll want to use a separate tool like https://github.com/Azure/data-lake-adlstool).  If you fail to set permissions to some of the files, then you do not have access to the file.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what's not working?

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter to early.  Can you provide more information on what's not working? Were there any failures when trying to recursively set all the child ACLs?  Also, what credentials are your analytics jobs using? Diagnosing these access issues can be difficult because of the scale of files/folders often involved, but it usually comes down to simply having an ACL set incorrectly or missing.

Comment: It solved. I gave permission to myself as owner in IAM. Now able to delete the files.